# Have a specific cell move to a different tab rather than the entire row

Tags: google-apps-script

I am super novice and wanted to get someone's input on how to make this work. I have been looking around and this has been the main topic. Which would send an ENTIRE row to another tab as the destination tab. But how to do you specify only to have one cell's information to the next tab. For example, I have names on Column A and I would only like to send the name and none of the information after that to the next google sheet tab once I get the value true.

```
function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named main
// target sheet of move to named Completed
// getColumn with check-boxes is currently set to column 4 or D
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Interviewer Training" && r.getColumn() == 16 && r.getValue() == true) {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("General IC SWE");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
} else if(s.getName() == "General IC SWE" && r.getColumn() == 16 && r.getValue() == false) {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Interviewer Training");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1):

To move a single cell value from the current sheet to the next sheet.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('flag1');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var idx=sh.getIndex();
  var tsh=nextSheet(e);
  //e.source.toast('Next Sheet: ' + tsh.getName());
  if(sh.getName()!="Sheet1")return;
  if(e.range.columnStart==1 && e.value=='TRUE' && !e.range.offset(0,1).isBlank() ) {
    //e.source.toast('flag2');
    tsh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,e.range.columnStart + 1).setValue(e.range.offset(0,1).getValue());
  }
}

function nextSheet(e) {
  //e.source.toast('flag3');
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var shts=e.source.getSheets();
  return shts[(sh.getIndex())%shts.length];
}
```

This is my sheet 1:

[image]

This is the next sheet:

[image]

I'm using the click of a checkbox to trigger the onEdit() function to make the transfer of the data immediately to the right of the selected check box and I move it to the same cell in the next sheet.  The next sheet is the sheet immediately to the right or if it's the last sheet on the right it moves to the first sheet.

[Sheet.getIndex()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getindex)

[Remainder or Modulo Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder)

Answer (score 0):

To move just a single cell you would only need to change your `s.getRange()`

```
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
```

To get cell in row X column B

```
s.getRange(row, 2, 1, 1).moveTo(target);
```

The get range uses these parameters;

```
.getRange(Row Number, Column Number, Number of Rows, Number of Columns)
```

You only need to edit Column Number and Number of Columns

So row X column C & D would be

```
s.getRange(row, 3, 1, 2).moveTo(target);
```